# How to retrieve value of data from database with SUM in one column

Tags: mysql, json, database, codeigniter

I have a function that retrieve values from database as json.I need some data from database and a value of SUM for certain column.When i not retrieve SUM from those value i get all required data but when i also include SUM function to get total of values from certain column i get only single object of value

MODEL

```
    public function search_tickets($data){
    $ticketDate = $data['ticket_date'];
    $ticketBus = $data['ticket_bus'];
    $ticketAgentId = $data['agent_id'];
        $user = $this->db->select("
        CONCAT_WS(' ', tp.firstname, tp.lastname) AS passenger_name,
        tb.seat_numbers AS seat_number,
        tb.id_no AS ticket_number,
        fr.reg_no AS bus_number,
        DATE_FORMAT(ta.start_date, '%d/%m/%Y') as ticket_date,
        tb.price AS fare_paid,
                tb.pickup_trip_location AS boarding,
                tb.drop_trip_location AS dropping,
                    SUM(tb.price) AS total_fare
            ")
        ->from('tkt_booking AS tb')
        ->join('tkt_passenger AS tp', 'tb.tkt_passenger_id_no = tp.id_no' ,'full')
        ->join('trip_assign AS ta', 'ta.id = tb.trip_id_no' ,'full')
        ->join('trip_route AS tr', 'tr.id = tb.trip_route_id','full')
        ->join('agent AS a', 'a.agent_id = tb.agent_id','full')
        ->join('fleet_registration AS fr', 'fr.id = ta.fleet_registration_id','full')
        ->where('ta.start_date', $ticketDate )
        ->where('fr.reg_no', $ticketBus )
        ->where('tb.agent_id', $ticketAgentId )
        ->get()
        ->result();
    return $user;
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
    public function searchTickets(){ 
                $data = $_POST; 
        $ticket=$this->booking_model->search_tickets($data);
        if($ticket){
            $result =  array('tickets'=>$ticket);
        } else {
            $result =  NULL;
        }
        print json_encode($result);
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide your query with the `SUM` that is giving you the problem? Though it sounds like it has to do with you not using `GROUP BY` correctly

Comment: @kchason the above query is that one give problem.If i remove  `SUM(tb.price) AS total_fare` from query i got all nedeed values without SUM

Comment: Oh, I missed that, sorry. So what is total_fare supposed to be? The total fare for all tickets, or per some split (agent, customer, etc)? You have `tb.price AS fare_paid` and then `SUM(tb.price) AS total_fare`. But either way, take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: @kchason What i need is sum for all passengers to give total value for example `fare_paid` for passenger 1 is 1000,`fare_paid` for passenger 2 is 1500,`fare_paid` for passenger 1 is 1000.I need a total`total_fare` value to be sum of 1000,1500 and 1000 = 3500

Answer (score 0):

You should `GROUP BY` passenger id to get the total sum for each passenger:

```
 $this->db->group_by('tb.tkt_passenger_id_no');
```

Comment: Depending on which version of MySQL OP is using, this will cause warnings/errors as each field should be either in an aggregate function or in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: What i need is sum for all passengers to give total value for example price for passenger 1 is 1000,price for passenger 2 is 1500,price for passenger 1 is 1000.I need a total value to be sum of 1000,1500 and 1000 = 3500